# findByIdAndRemove getting status 404

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to delete a record by using the _id, however i've getting a status 404 from postman. Where did things go wrong here?

```
router.delete('/sale/delete/:id', function(req, res) {

    Sale.findByIdAndRemove({
            _id: req.params.id
        },
        function(err, respRaw) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            res.status(204).json(respRaw)
        })
});
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the request in an image or the request URI?

Comment: use ```if (err) { console.log(err); return;} ...``` or ```if (err) {console.log(err) } else {res.status(204).json(respRaw)}```

Comment: I think I found it for you: modify from ```'sale/delete/:id'``` to ```'/api/sale/delete/:id'```. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: api/sale is actually correct, i've app.get('/api', cors(), (req, res, next) => {  in my main js script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add as a supplement for the author's answer:

`findByIdAndRemove()` was confused with `findOneAndRemove()`, namely its parameters.

---

[findByIdAndRemove()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove):

Parameters

- id «Object|Number|String» value of _id to query by
- [options] «Object» optional
- [options.strict] «Boolean|String» overwrites the schema's strict mode option
- [callback] «Function»

Returns:

- «Query»

Issue a mongodb findAndModify remove command by a document's _id field.

> `findByIdAndRemove(id, ...)` is equivalent to `findOneAndRemove({ _id: id }, ...)`.

Finds a matching document, removes it, passing the found document (if any) to the callback.

Executes the query if callback is passed.

---

[findOneAndRemove()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove):

Parameters

- conditions «Object»
- [options] «Object» optional
- [options.strict] «Boolean|String» overwrites the schema's strict mode option
- [callback] «Function»

Returns:

- «Query»

Issue a mongodb findAndModify remove command.

Finds a matching document, removes it, passing the found document (if any) to the callback.

Executes the query if callback is passed.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to explain in my example but it think ur answer is very complete

Comment: @mark5 I'm happy for us. Your question was valid and interesting too. I learned a lot too. You have my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by using

```
Sale.findByIdAndRemove(id, options, function(err, respRaw) {}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. So basically you confused ```findByIdAndRemove()``` with ```findOneAndRemove()```, right? And you also missed ```options``` parameter? But it's optional. Also why brackets in the end?
Could you add these to your answer and make it more clearer please. No matter I'll do it.